# Where to find the app store on Ubuntu phone?

Tags: package-management, ubuntu-touch

I am using a BQ Aquarius E4.5Q smartphone with Ubuntu.
Looking for the app store.
Does anyone know where I can find it?

Answer (score 2):

There's an "Apps" scope. On the very bottom of it is a big orange button that will open the appstore. It's the one scope that can't be removed, so it should always be available by swiping left or right moving through the scopes.